# jQuery id^= not working?

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to simulate a click on multiple buttons which all start with the same id values. I did not make this site I'm trying to make a script so users don't have to press every button. Selecting the individual id works but when I try to use id^= it does not:

```
$(id='UnsubscribeItemBtn485527146')
<a href=​"javascript:​UnsubscribeItem( '485527146', '255710' )​;​" id=​"UnsubscribeItemBtn485527146" class=​"btn_grey_black btn_medium">​…​</a>

$(id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn')
0
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?
If I'm being really stupid go easy I'm new to this!
​

Comment: If you need help with code, please post **real** code.

Comment: Neither of your two selectors make any sense.

Comment: maybe I've fallen off, but I don't think any of that stuff you posted makes sense anywhere.  maybe if you combined jquery with pythons kwargs?  Even then no idea what the ^ is supposed to do.

Comment: @Rooster I just replied you in the comment: `[attr^=value]`:
*Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".*.  Check out [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use it this way:

```
$("[id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn']")
```

You forgot the `[""]` notation.

1. Wrap the whole selector (the inside one) inside `"` quotes.
2. Attribute selectors need to be wrapped inside `[]` square brackets.

Hope this is clear. Thanks.

Comment: what does that even do?  serious question. never seen a syntax with that `^` before

Comment: @Rooster `[attr^=value]`:
*Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".*

Comment: jQuery starts-with selector: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: @Rooster Check out [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: oh wow.  Didn't know about that!  Thanks ++ :D